# How to separate a text file into columns

Tags: r

This is what my text file looks like:

```
1241105.41129.97Y317052.03
2282165.61187.63N364051.40
2251175.87190.72Y366447.49
2243125.88150.81N276045.45
328192.89117.68Y295050.51
2211140.81165.77N346053.11
1291125.61160.61Y335048.3
3273127.73148.76Y320048.04
2191132.22156.94N336051.38
3221118.73161.03Y349349.5
2341189.01200.31Y360048.02
1253144.45180.96N305051.51
2251125.19152.75N305052.72
2192137.82172.25N240046.96
3351140.96174.85N394048.09
1233135.08173.36Y265049.82
1201112.59140.75N380051.25
2202128.19159.73N307048.29
2192132.82172.25Y240046.96
3351148.96174.85Y394048.09
1233132.08173.36N265049.82
1231114.59140.75Y380051.25
3442128.19159.73Y307048.29
2323179.18191.27N321041.12
```

All these values are continuous and each character indicates something. I am unable to figure out how to separate each value into columns and specify a heading for all these new columns which will be created.

I used this code, however it does not seem to work.

```
birthweight <- read.table("birthweighthw1.txt", sep="", col.names=c("ethnic","age","smoke","preweight","delweight","breastfed","brthwght","brthlngth”))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your attempt indicates you want to break each row up into eight columns. But there are more than eight characters per line in your text file. How do you want them broken up?

Comment: I kind of wonder how your data got into this format in the first place

Comment: If you know the widths for each column you could implement a fixed width solution. Perhaps [`read.fwf`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.fwf.html)?

Comment: Thank you everyone for replying, so if you look at 1st column is an indicator of RACE. Column 2 and 3 its an indicator of age. 4th column is an indicator of sex= M or F. So if i could separate all of these values into their respective classification would be great. I even tried using read.fwf(), I am still stuck.

Comment: And every column has  a variable width based on their classification.

Comment: I don't see any M or F in the data. How is this encoded, then? Also, the values seem to be separated by dots. What is the meaning of that?

Comment: you're looking for help on SO, you have to be more clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a clear definition for every column, you can use regular expressions to solve this in no time.

From your column names and example data, I guess that the regular expression that matches each field is:

```
ethnic: \d{1}
age: \d{1,2}
smoke: \d{1}
preweight: \d{3}\.\d{2}
delweight: \d{3}\.\d{2}
breastfed: Y|N
brthwght: \d{3}
brthlngth: \d{3}\.\d{1,2}
```

We can put all this together in a regular expression that captures each of these fields

```
reg.expression <- "(\\d{1})(\\d{1,2})(\\d{1})(\\d{3}\\.\\d{2})(\\d{3}\\.\\d{2})(Y|N)(\\d{3})(\\d{3}\\.\\d{1,2})"
```

Note: In R, we need to scape "\" that's why we write \d instead of \d.

That said, here comes the code to solve the problem.

First, you need to read your strings

```
lines <- readLines("birthweighthw1.txt")
```

Now, we define our regular expression and use the function `str_match` from the package `stringr` to get your data into character matrix.

```
require(stringr)

reg.expression <- "(\\d{1})(\\d{1,2})(\\d{1})(\\d{3}\\.\\d{2})(\\d{3}\\.\\d{2})(Y|N)(\\d{3})(\\d{3}\\.\\d{1,2})"

captured <- str_match(string= lines, pattern= reg.expression)
```

You can check that the first column in the matrix contains the text matched, and the following columns the data captured. So, we can get rid of the first column

```
captured <- captured[,-1]
```

and transform it into a data.frame with appropriate column names

```
result <- as.data.frame(captured,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

names(result) <- c("ethnic","age","smoke","preweight","delweight","breastfed","brthwght","brthlngth")
```

Now, every column in result is of type character, you can transform each of them into other types. For example:

```
require(dplyr)

result <- result %>% mutate(ethnic=as.factor(ethnic),
                            age=as.integer(age),
                            smoke=as.factor(smoke),
                            preweight=as.numeric(preweight),
                            delweight=as.numeric(delweight),
                            breastfed=as.factor(breastfed),
                            brthwght=as.integer(brthwght),
                            brthlngth=as.numeric(brthlngth)
                            )
```